# Toggle a reverse animation when a button is clicked the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to animate a menu.The menu button is a div which has an animation as well with a click event. I succesfully got the menu to beatifully appear on the screen, but i can't get it to leave it as well, preferably with the same, but reversed, animation. This is my html:

```
<div class="dropdown-meniu">
    <div class="buton-meniu" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-meniu-content">
        <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used for the moment the solution that W3 Schools provides for the dropdown, as well for the animation of the button. This is the styling of the menu and the animation:

```
.dropdown-meniu-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #696969;
    width: 35%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
    animation-name: slideIn-meniu;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn-meniu;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes slideIn-meniu {
    from { transform: translateX(100%); opacity: 0.5;  }
    to { margin-right: 0px; opacity: 1; } 
}

.show {
    display:block;
}
```

If it is necessary, I will post the other CSS. For the script, I have used jQuery and javascript for the two animations(I am a noob at JavaScript/jQuery so I couldn't get it to work with only JavaScript/jQuery alone and I know that jquery is slow to load but I am using it for other things).

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
 This is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfv7qL7z/3/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to animate between `display: none` and `display: block` which doesn't work.  You need to hide the element in some other manner, like a negative offset, and then animate it to be visible.

Modify your `.dropdown-meniu-content` rule to start offscreen and to have a `transition` property.  Then have `.show` reset the `transform` back to `translateX(0%)`:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 10000px;
    background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206, 0.2);
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

.meniu {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}

.buton-meniu {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.dropdown-meniu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-meniu-content {
    top: 110px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #696969;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 10000px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
    
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 1s ease;
    
    animation-name: slideIn-meniu;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn-meniu;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

@keyframes slideIn-meniu {
    from {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    to {
        margin-right: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.show {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
    <div class="meniu">
        <div class="dropdown-meniu">
            <div class="buton-meniu" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-meniu-content">
                <p>TEST </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code is working as it should. I am new to web development in general and wasn't accustomed to transition and translate, thus i used animation. I learnt something new today, and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you need, but maybe something like this? I pulled out the `display: none` and stripped down the animations a bit.

HTML

```
   <div class="dropdown-meniu">
    <div class="buton-meniu" onclick="myFunction(this)">
      <div class="bar1">Click Me</div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-meniu-content hide">
      <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
    .dropdown-meniu-content {
   /*      display: none; */
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #696969;
        width: 35%;
        max-width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        right: 0;

    }
    @keyframes slideIn-meniu {
        from { opacity: 0.5;  }
        to { opacity: 1; } 
    }
    @keyframes slideOut-meniu {
        from { opacity: 1;  }
        to { opacity: 0.5; } 
    }
    .show {
        display:block;
        right: 0;
        transition: right 0.6s;

        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        -webkit-animation-name: slideIn-meniu;
        animation-duration: 0.6s ease;
    }
    .hide {
      right: -35%;
      transition: right 0.6s ease;
      display: block;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
       -webkit-animation-name: slideOut-meniu;
        animation-duration: 0.6s ease;
    }
```

jQuery

```
$('.bar1').click(function(){
 $('.dropdown-meniu-content').toggleClass('show').toggleClass('hide');
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/282vpcm2/15/

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean. I am not at the computer right now, but i will try tomorrow to see if i can get the animation on buton-meniu to work as well. I asume i could just insert the function that adds  the change class? For me "buton-meniu" are three bars and when pressed, they change to an X shape. That is the trouble for me(since i am a noob) to make buton-meniu trigger the menu to open and close with an animation and trigger the animation for those three bars. If there are problems, i will come back tomorrow with the rest of the code.

Comment: I have some problems with your version, and i can't get it to work. I have edited the post to include a jsFiddle.

Comment: @TakeDown I see you've updated the post. You should use zero298's response as a starting point and work from there.